# `repository.create` strips values of columns that are both arrays and embedded objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Given a simple `Foo` entity, which in turn contains a collection of `Bar` objects in mongodb

problem occurs **only if a column is both an array and an embedded object**.

```
@Entity()
export class Foo {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  public id: ObjectID;

  @Column()
  public simple: string;

  @Column(type => Bar)
  public collection: Bar[];
}

export class Bar {
  @Column()
  value: boolean;
}
```

`repository.create` transforms the raw value

```
{
  "simple": "string",
  "collection": [
    { "value": true },
    { "value": false }
  ]
}
```

into simply

```
{ "simple": "string" }
```

I just took this from https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2342 but same thing is happening on my end

Comment: Still having problems?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this is a [bug](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1980) in typeorm. As a workaround, you can set the collection manually until the issue is solved:

```
async createFoo(createFooDto) {
  const newFoo = await this.repository.create(createFooDto);
  // TODO: Remove when https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1980 is solved
  newFoo.collection = createFooDto.collection;
  this.repository.save(newFoo);
}
```

If this is a regression (it used to work) you can try to downgrade typeorm until it is fixed.